# Bootstrap expanding sidebar containers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sidebar, expand

Ive been experimenting with Bootstrap lately trying to make a new website. What I want to implement is a 2 column system (main body area with sticky sidebar that has individual containers inside). I want the containers inside my sidebar to be able to expand to show more content and then collapse back to normal onclick independent of the sidebar itself. The main body area scrolls independent of the sidebar and visa versa, and they are meant to behave as two separate areas.

So essentially: 
1. sidebar will have a defined width 
2. click one of the containers inside the sidebar and that container expands width and height overlapping over the main body.
3. dont want it to shift the overall layout, just expand to show more content.

This is my current HTML:

```
<body>

<header class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" id="header">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
        <img alt="EQO" id="logo" src="EQO.png"></img>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Search" name="q">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">            
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href='#'>
                        Discover!
                    </a>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="modal" href='#signup'>
                        Sign up
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#login">
                        Login
                    </a>
                </li>
        </ul>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</header>

<div class="container-fluid" id="main">
<!--main area-->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column col-md-10" id="middle">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="profile_picture" style=" margin-bottom: 10px; background: #ccc;">

            </div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                  <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                  <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="col-md-12" style="height: 100%; background: #ccc;">

            </div>
        </div>

<!--widget area-->
        <div class="column col-md-2" id="sidebar">
            <div class="col-md-12" id="widget1">
                Sample widget 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" id="widget2">
                Sample widget 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" id="widget1">
                Sample widget 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" id="widget2">
                Sample widget 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" id="widget1">
                Sample widget 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" id="widget2">
                Sample widget 1
            </div> 
            <div class="col-md-12" id="widget1">
                Sample widget 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" id="widget2">
                Sample widget 1
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12" id="widget1">
                Sample widget 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom" id="footer" >
<!--footer area-->
    <div class="col-md-12" id="footer_content" >

    </div>
</div>  

</body>
```

This is a mockup i made to show how I want the sidebar to behave.
[sidebar example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRVmp.png)

Im just not sure how to implement this along side what I have already. I dont know if Im just overlooking something completely but I dont think it could be solved with just css magic and Bootstrap thats why Im asking for help. I know there is the collapse and accordion features but those dont seem to give me the effect Im wanting to go for, unless they can be modified in a way to actually work then hey Im all ears.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you have to define a new row for every widget (you can have nested row):

```
<div class="column col-md-2" id="sidebar">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="widget1">
      blabla
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" id="widget2">
      blabla
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Second, for the collapse/expand, you have to add jquery and set, on the trigger:

```
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ID_OF_TARGET"
```

And on the target, the right id :

```
class="collapse in"
```

The "in" is here to force the data to be expanded at startup.

I did [a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnpsagzb/) as an example using panel and [one with simple div](https://jsfiddle.net/cha0zpmt/). Hope it helps!

Comment: I like this, but I wanted it to expand its width and height, not just accordion or collapse. This isnt specifically being made for mobile

Comment: My bad I didn't get it and I'm still unsure of what you want. Is it something [like an overlay](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp) ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by setting the body to full height, and `overflow:hidden`. The allow overflow on each of the columns. This can be done inside a media query so that columns stack vertically on smaller screens...

```
   body {
      overflow: hidden;
   }

   #main, #main>.row {
      height: 100%;
   }

  #left {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-y: auto; 
  }

  #right {
    top: 0;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/uTJG2ELrRP

Comment: What I was wanting was more along the lines of a horizontal and vertical expand, not just an accordion or collapse. Doesnt have to be focused on making it for a smaller screen

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to make some effort to tweak this. SO is not a coding service.

Comment: I know SO isnt... In my question I stated that i know about accordion and collapse and what you commented was exactly that.